# Multiple extends condition in one liner in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I am converting my `javascript` project to `typescript` and I am on the learning stage and learned a lot from converting my project. I had one challenge on my code and I resolved it but the problem is I have multiple conditions on that and I can not `extends` 4 and 5 times for same result.

Here is the code

```
type GetModel<M> = IsUnion<M> extends true
  ? UserModel
  : M extends typeof types.FRONT
  ? UserModel
  : AdminModel;
```

Playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsFsEsDsDmoBmAnGoA2sBGaBDNATwChSAXYgBwFNQBVeWSeAFUgEl4La0BnWgGMKLeAB4mYgHygAvKAAUpAJAhQAA1oAPXvAAm-UAFd4Aa3iQA7vA2hYRglisFiRxJATIKkULnoUABb0QgSCoAQG9kbGgvqgPqBCrABufBQJwarqGlKsdgiJBKAA2voOFGh4xqJpSazloqxO2WBUdAC6ioEUFNT8AFwgViMAdO20-EJV1BRYkYijkGiIwPqQQvzAgZH6uJCQZsBotFi0YbQAtJa8WxNTMxSXAEyXAByjPdBYAMTl-JVqrUrskDLAmvAnJd7gBKUaqPLwUA6PSGEzmSw2VRqMBsYLosQJGj0BwmOIRIxBeisLDECIrYzQWg8BK+YooUwiQn8BBCAL40xibHqSAoVCciH0xCM5kUIykyL2Hh8QRc1jwlQqAD8Sn+gNwNVo+kRA0YzFYMPkshSnn0wtxgVJVlYAHIMjtqHR4BqVKb4LQ0mh7aBuCg+Jl6BpuLwBMIIXYJqAefA+aA2MSAMrTWCzUAnagnQQ8Sn46iQHkQlqa9REaVM4ugUUE1hGJsclMQxyOJGFFVxwlNqnN72kS0o5loxSKJkrI3Rvtq+CmhBhtAh5WxxeWuTW20w1Q6+ebiGqP0BvgAbnIic4-ER4jYsgUJTYHWRugnRhKiI4R9VEIfaQ3x1FAnHCU1KmMWgr3IdRLnghDEKQ5CUMQ2CwAAQREYwnAgSB9Foch6ngAEiToIwFAAb1IUAIAAWQzU0AEYABoaNAAAxAAlAB5AA5NhTWeNiAF8KWIgEYMTAAFeYKBQZZoHTOh5FAJjQAAH1AZ4r0TBhBDQOj8NOVSXViPgXV04lQAw-Q4HgIyCKwUyCDshBLOvayAHFaAoRzTnEOinxDO9zQkIL31RSk0Cg9idX0vh-KwdjTToyLPzI2hB2JfhRm4-i2DixgDKSlKbLchzjKwKTrPMtcFB8vyqvEdStOeaQrJUur1Ia3ykvEdrOvoVz7NUxr+qYjqgA)

I want to convert above code to something that might linear, something like below but I don't why it is not working

```
type GetModel<M> = IsUnion<M> extends true | M extends typeof types.FRONT
  ? UserModel
  : AdminModel;
```

I want same result as I have right now in my playground link.

```
type user = GetModel<1 | 2>; // user
type user1 = GetModel<2>; // user
type admin = GetModel<1>; // admin
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGBO9m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it is great but I have 4 to 5 conditions for same result, can you do that?

Comment: Sure, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgakMm) work?

Comment: xDD, I didn't understand anything but type admin is printing "user", can you please check

Comment: because I added dummy conditions to show that you can add many conditions. If you check the conditions array you will see couple of `true`

Comment: If you replace `true` with `false` then everything works fine. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYlpbm)

Comment: It is great but if you can explain me little bit of what you did on answer, it will be awesome.....

Comment: sure, will do soon

Comment: I know you may have more than just two types, but for simpler cases, utilizing basic type theory and `extends` behavior makes it really simple: `2 extends M`: https://tsplay.dev/Wkad9N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the simple or, which accepts two conditions and returns `true` if any of the conditions are true, otherwise returns `false`.

We will need some utility types from the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package:

[Extends](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/extends.d.ts?plain=1#L16) - Returns boolean whether the first argument extends the second argument

```
type Extends<T, Base> = T extends Base ? true : false;
```

[If](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/if.d.ts) - Returns the second argument if the first argument is `true` (defaults to `true`), otherwise returns the third argument (defaults to `false`)

```
type If<
  Condition,
  IfTrue = true,
  IfFalse = false
> = Condition extends true ? IfTrue : IfFalse;
```

[IfExtends](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/extends.d.ts?plain=1#L40) - Returns the third argument if the first argument extends the second argument (defaults to `true`), otherwise returns the fourth argument (defaults to `false`):

```
type IfExtends<T, Base, IfTrue = true, IfFalse = false> = If<
  Extends<T, Base>,
  IfTrue,
  IfFalse
>;
```

[IsEmptyArray](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/array.d.ts#L40) - Returns a boolean whether the first parameter is an empty array:

```
type IsEmptyArray<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly [
  unknown,
  ...unknown[]
]
  ? false
  : true;
```

So, for the simple or we can just use `If` and if the first condition is `true` we return `true`, otherwise we return a boolean whether the second condition is `true`:

```
type Or<Condition1, Condition2> = IfExtends<
    Condition1,
    true,
    true,
    IfExtends<Condition2, true>
```

Testing:

```
// true
type Case1 = Or<true, true>
// true
type Case2 = Or<true, false>
// true
type Case3 = Or<false, true>
// false
type Case4 = Or<false, false>
```

For more than two conditions we will need another type named `OrArr` which will accept an array of conditions.
Algorithm:

- Return `true` if the array is empty
- Pop the first condition
- If the array is empty return a `boolean` whether the first condition is `true`
- Else pop the second condition from the array
- Check if the first condition or the second condition is `true`

  - If any of the conditions are `true` return `true`
  - Else run the `OrArr` for the rest of the array

Implementation:

```
type OrArr<Conditions extends readonly unknown[]> =
  IsEmptyArray<Conditions> extends true
  ? true
  : Conditions extends readonly [
    infer Condition1,
    ...infer Rest extends readonly unknown[],
  ]
  ? IsEmptyArray<Rest> extends true
  ? Extends<Condition1, true>
  : Rest extends [
    infer Condition2,
    ...infer Rest2 extends readonly unknown[],
  ]
  ? Or<Condition1, Condition2> extends true
  ? true
  : OrArr<Rest2>
  : false
  : false;
```

We use the [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword to get the first element and the rest of the elements from the array

Testing:

```
// true
type Case1 = OrArr<[true]>
// true
type Case2 = OrArr<[true, false]>
// true
type Case3 = OrArr<[false, false, false, true, false]>
// false
type Case4 = OrArr<[false, false, false, false, false]>
```

Usage:

```
type GetModel<M> = OrArr<[IsUnion<M>, Extends<M, typeof types.FRONT>]> extends true
  ? UserModel
  : AdminModel;
```

Final testing:

```
// "user"
type user = GetModel<1 | 2>;
// "user"
type user1 = GetModel<2>;
// "admin"
type admin = GetModel<1>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQGYFEAeMCmA7AEwGcAaOLXQ0lI9cGATwEEooBDBuAXzlSghBwA5IzA4AtETYgAru2BCAUMpyZIsOKJxwA8lAA8AYQiFgMYCYCMZY6fMmATAD44AXhQZs+YvsVw4tgRmFnjWfppQMjgk4TCR0eFoFN5ERiZB9ngOZHFRTor5iqrq8Fq6UCwGgcEmRHCqlMRwUDhsBCYANpwyeADWeBAA7ngA2gC6Lq6JtPTMrBxpdiFELg0pEVHhAPwbOOEAXAHpNXh1a1TNre14XXAj4f7AeKg4UEdLVjH+-gB0f08vN4AJRwRHg5yaLTanW6fQGw3GXzgY22NDoYEYlQWILBqy8F1ye38O2SVEWGRC1l2+X8hxx4PxTXu3zgANe7wpjiRv3+z3Z9Ic9UZdSh11uPX6Q1GYyRKOJ5XJJyp1UyziFjTqhNRWtp5Uq+gFNLgh1QbA6RCJxt4ZotAG5lAB6B1HEBPADmvH4gg6wAARuwoAxlGUAKp4EIAFQgyDwuCgFoAxpl9GGQpM4AAKcJOuAAAwhdQl8LwudZdTNgw4dTdEHdmggcF92hgAAttAm2Ba4GxCGW4DILQR63AEyYAG6vUpt7PO3Opkylp4wBtsO5BMFQP0ycwTkfHTJmmeaBhiMYZlswGBgIj7J2De8-LREBObjEdHtun7QN0O9oJogOi2PYEL6EAQL0DotB0rQWuIAy4ABT4vsAGLiA44gABw-BeIAdAAxOucRbjuEijh8eBmuIT4AJQ-OE854Oq6xFlKR4Rm2-bhiYx5iH2A44EOnaaBxMLdlAboyCA+ClCuvA9EmIRwEQTwJs2HE9CER4QKgcl4Ap3FsOJknSXUwDloxS6vImmR0fKGaEZuvrbgJDGHAx1FuC4Y61gQbEtmZcCDCYIhwEBYBiHgtlWngOATlAR4xoCwnaLmMZxtZISlmUyl6doEYnjgADKyEYpcYAtBasaahxkDKQeHRHoZElSVVcDaZxyxtTpqDyZk5bmaysZWTg+mMe1rbaBpJh0R5BaZhmUniQJaXDaNhxsm8K3xiNmQea4Xk+dRqJbRlJgHHAMVxfaihlMgRAMfoEbpiMEZjExFwjAxUYnTtISPU4b07Ka5raIchLXYoObiNDMOw3D8MI7DjrOkwSYyGaRwEHsihkWCPGgm4iDhIYACyhWHGE-gAGJAjoAByEaHNkig8EJuMwNdZQAArvjAqDQCA+W8e4lhwAAPnADj2qGFpQCTEBYx0hNCPxUBCNLBVwEwBCung8uK8rbS6+rwaawA4jgMD6zgHT6CT6Z6PqIx3Q99tkKSPgkzkBXjQVRA-DT9NPWQwMWiHNrRNaIMTO9TQ6nAOwhrL1sNbq2u6yn105gARKr2c3ZrquExbVsKzb+iixLzj2jnecF7xqui+4Jcp-o1eQ862dG08+dlN3jHN5breWE49pAA)

Comment: That `OrArr` implementation is totally unnecessary... https://tsplay.dev/NnBdVN

Comment: No idea, how I missed that, thanks